# Test Execution stops when code throws Excetion - I have to press F5 again to resume - Everything seems to work - But am I executing my tests correct?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, mocking, flutter-test

I am running tests against a Flutter app, things are being mocked with mocktail.dart. Testing frameworks in use are bloc_test.dart and flutter_test.dart.

By the way the code is from Felix Angelov's bloc repository:
https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_infinite_list/test/posts/bloc/post_bloc_test.dart

Normally when I press F5, while having a test file visible in VS Code, my tests just executes and I get this comfortable green of all the tests passed.

**But when a test includes an exception thrown in the code, VS Code stops the execution of the tests, and I have to press F5 to continue.**

It seems to me that both the code and the test works as they should, and the test also passes after I press F5 to resume the execution of the tests.

But my life would be a little more comfortable if I did not have to press F5 to resume the test suite when an Exception is being tested.

**Am I executing my test in the right way?
Is it perfectly normal, that I have to press F5 again, to resume the tests, after an exception has been thrown?**

This is how VS Code looks like when the test execution stops due to an exception thrown:
[image]

Code under test looks something like this:

```
Future<PostState> _mapPostFetchedToState(PostState state) async {
  try {
        ...
        final posts = await _fetchPosts(state.posts.length);
        ...
        
  } on Exception {
    return state.copyWith(status: PostStatus.failure);
  }
}

Future<List<Post>> _fetchPosts([int startIndex = 0]) async {
  throw Exception('error fetching posts');
}
```

Test code looks like this:

```
blocTest<PostBloc, PostState>(
    'emits failure status when http fetches posts and throw exception',
    build: () {
      when(() => httpClient.get(any())).thenAnswer(
        (invocation) async => http.Response('', 500),
      );
      return PostBloc(httpClient: httpClient);
    },
    wait: const Duration(microseconds: 500),
    act: (bloc) => bloc.add(PostFetched()),
    expect: () =>
        <PostState>[const PostState(status: PostStatus.failure)],
    verify: (_) {
      verify(() => httpClient.get(_postsUrl(start: 0))).called(1);
});
```

Comment: Debuggers are often configured to break when exceptions are thrown.  Throwing exceptions is not necessarily a problem; sometimes exceptions are used for control flow.  Throwing exceptions is a problem only if they're unexpected or are uncaught.

Comment: @jamesdlin My life would be a little more comfortable if I did not have to press F5 again when a test including an exception is being executed.

Comment: You can run without debugging with Ctrl+F5.  I don't know if there's a way to disable automatically breaking on exceptions in VS Code.

Comment: @jamesdlin Ah yeah, Run Without Debugging, that was what I was looking for. Now all my test becomes green without me having to press F5 again. Now the question is answered by you.